# Property just has default value in code-behind - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties, dependency-properties

I'm using some UserControls that automatically "register" in a dictionary in the main window. The UserControls have some values set to them in the main window's XAML.
I've implemented Dependency Properties and all that, working fine.
But when I'm accessing the values from custom properties like

```
Main.Conn.RequestStatus(sf.Address);
```

the property is returning the default value I set in the class definiton.

```
public string Address {get; set;} = "";
```

However when I call

```
Main.Conn.RequestStatus((string)GetValue(AddressProperty)));
```

it's working as it should (Address being "1/11").

Why is that? Do I have to get property values with the Dependecy Property methods? Or did I implement the properties the wrong way?

Comment: _"Or did I implement the properties the wrong way?"_ Probably. Please share the code, so we can actually say "yes" or "no".

Comment: Looking at your code, I wonder where Address is. I think Clemens has a good point but it's based on it being the wrapper for your dp. Maybe it is instead in a viewmodel and there's some binding problem. Please show us more code and explain how this is supposed to fit together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration

```
public string Address {get; set;} = "";
```

is not a valid wrapper for a dependency property.

It must look like this:

```
public string Address
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(AddressProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AddressProperty, value); }
}
```

The dependency property identifier field should be defined like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AddressProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Address),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(YourControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(""));
```